# Jquery - get next element by class and hide current

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement the showing of part of content(5 positions at each part) by clicking on the "load more" div but stuck with getting the next element by class. 

For better view here is example on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8ya7bbm2/1/ 
The problem is in the last line:

```
size_li = $("#myList li").size();
x=3;
$('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
$('.loadMore').click(function () {
    x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').slideDown();
    $(this).hide().nextAll('.loadMore').show(); // working
   // $(this).hide().next('.loadMore').show(); NOT WORKING...
```

The main idea is that after all content will be shown the "load more" must be hidden so that users can understand that this is all of content. At the moment I almost done what I wanted but .next is not working as I expected. When I use .nextAll it works great, but I need only next element by class, not all next elements of that class.
Also maybe this version is a little bit ugly and there is more simplest way to do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.first()` to target only first element in matched set:

```
$(this).hide().nextAll('.loadMore').first().show();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ucn28zdm/)**

Answer (score 0):

[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will not work in this case, because `next` will check for only immediately following sibling. You can use `.nextAll('.loadMore:first')` like following.

```
$(this).hide().nextAll('.loadMore:first').show();
```